# MVN release:prepare with Mercurial push FAIL

Tags: mercurial, release, push, prepare

Here's the steps I take:

1. Clone mercurial project at the head.
2. On local repository, perform `hg status` (no results), then `hg in` (no changes).
3. `mvn clean install`. Build is successful.
4. `mvn release:prepare`.

Get's to the point where it's excuting a push

```
[INFO] EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "hg push http://remoterepo/hg.project"
[ERROR]
EXECUTION FAILED
   Execution of cmd : push failed with exit code: -1
   Your Hg installation seems to be valid and complete. Hg version: 1.8.4 (OK)
```

Doing a `hg status` I now have:

```
? pom.xml.releaseBackup
? release.properties
```

From my understanding is that this happens when it could be creating a branch on the remote repo and the fix is to make sure I'm on the head. I'm on the head.

I've done this several times before and now this happens. Let me reiterate, I cloned the head and I couldn't clone a branch if I wanted to as none exist.

Now what? How do I fix this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Joe

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It was a authentication thing. The Maven release plugin does not use the authentication details in `<project>/.hg/hgrc` but it DOES in `/<Users>/<UserName>/.hgrc`. After I updated my password everything worked just fine.

Comment: Even when doing this I still get the same issue.

Comment: Was able to figure it out, was a configuration issue on my side. Bitbucket now requires SSL authentication.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what happens when you try to do an `hg push` yourself on the command line ? If everything's fine you definitively have a problem, otherwise the error message should help you determine what is going wrong.

If I were you, I would check if I have the right to push to the remote destination.

Is `http://remoterepo/hg.project` the real output or did you changed it for confidentiality reason ? If it's the real output, you should check your Maven configuration to put the real repository path.

Concerning the output of `hg status` after the steps, it's totally normal, Maven creates some file in the directory. You can add them to your `.hgignore` file so Mercurial won't show them to you. More information about that in [the documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html).

Comment: Thanks krtek for the response. Yes I can do a hg push at the command line without issue. Yes the URL to the project is changed ;-)

Comment: I tried using -Dusername and -Dpassword in hopes that might help. Nope.

Comment: @user1042520 Sorry, I don't know what other things it can be apart from a right problems.

Comment: Thanks Krtek. Wish there was a way to know what was causing the push to fail otherwise it's just a guess. Guess that's a downfall of hg.

Comment: More a downfall of Maven which isn't showing the entire error message ;) Usually command line errors are pretty good.